# To split data into good and bad rows and write to output file using Spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I am trying to filter the good and bad rows by counting the number of delimiters in a TSV.gz file and write to separate files in HDFS

I ran the below commands in spark-shell

```
Spark Version: 1.6.3

val file = sc.textFile("/abc/abc.tsv.gz")

val data = file.map(line => line.split("\t"))

var good = data.filter(a => a.size == 995)

val bad = data.filter(a => a.size < 995)
```

When I checked the first record the value could be seen in the spark shell

```
good.first()
```

But when I try to write to an output file I am seeing the below records,

```
good.saveAsTextFile(good.tsv)
```

**Output in HDFS (top 2 rows):**

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1287b635
[Ljava.lang.String;@2ef89922
```

Could ypu please let me know on how to get the required output file in HDFS

Thanks.!

Comment: I think the output is correct. It is just when Scala prints to screen Arrays it looks this way. Try to cast it to List and then print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final RDD is type of `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]`. Which leads to writing objects instead of string values in the write operation.

You should convert the array of strings to tab separated string values again before saving. Just try;

```scala
good.map(item => item.mkString("\t")).saveAsTextFile("goodFile.tsv")
```